# A System of Infinite Linear Equations

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, orthogonality

Suppose that $\{a_{i}\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$ with $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_{i} \lt \infty$ is known and that $\{b_i\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is such that

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_{i}b_{-i} =1,$$

and that, for all $k \in \mathbb Z/\{0\}$,

$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_{i}b_{-i+k} =0.$$

Is it possible to solve for $\{b_{i}\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$ as a function of $\{a_{i}\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$?

I just can't figure out where to start from.

Comment: could you please just give a simple example?

Comment: Take $a_0=\lambda,b_0=1/\lambda$ and all other terms 0. That seems to work, so the solutions certainly cannot be unique.

Comment: @almagest I don't think that is the case. Notice that $b_0$ appears in the summations that need to be zero as well.

Comment: Sure but it will be with a zero $a_i$. The only equation that puts the non-zero $a_i$ with the non-zero $b_j$ will be the first one.

Comment: @almagest $\{a_{i}\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is given. The idea is to solve for $\{b_{i}\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$ as a function of $\{a_{i}\}_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Ah, sorry. So if you were given $a_0=a_1=1$ and all other $a_i=0$ then $1-k=b_1=b_3=b_5=\dots$, and $k-1=b_2=b_4=b_6=\dots$ and $k=b_0=b_{-2}=b_{-4}=\dots$ and $-k=b_{-1}=b_{-3}=\dots$ would be a solution for any  $k$.

Comment: Yes, this is a "shift-orthogonality constraint" you will find in lots of signal processing when defining families of digital filters ( for example ).

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you for this. I arrived at these equation while trying to solve a filtering problem. Could you suggest a reference for where I could find more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to get the analytical solution because computing a numerical method is forced. If you want to obtain the exact solution, it needs modify the problem definition. The following description is redefined from the above original question:

> **Problem:** Suppose the $[a_{i}]$ and $[b_{i}]$, and then we add the new condition that $b_{n+k}=b_{-n+k}$ is set. Then, solve the following
>   system equations:
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=-n}^n a_{i}b_{-i+k}= \begin{cases} 1 &
>  (k=0) \\ \\ 0 & (\text{otherwise}) \end{cases} $$

Herewith, [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) appears in left side. When we want to estimate the infinity convolution between non-periodic functions, we use the [periodic summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_summation) of one hand signal. This operation is very important in signal processing. Additionally, the equation can be expressed by linear algebra such like matrix and vectors:

$$
\mathsf{A} \ \boldsymbol{b}=\boldsymbol{v}
$$

where

$$
\mathsf{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{-n} & a_{n} & a_{n-1} & \cdots &  a_{1-n} \\
a_{1-n} & a_{-n} & a_{n} & \cdots &  a_{2-n} \\
a_{2-n} & a_{1-n} & a_{-n} & \cdots &  a_{3-n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\
a_{n} & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \cdots & a_{-n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\boldsymbol{b}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{-n} & b_{-n+1} & \cdots & b_{n-1} & b_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
^{\text{T}}
$$

and $\boldsymbol{v}$ is all zero vector except last element as one:

$$
\boldsymbol{v}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
^{\text{T}}
$$

Particularly, the matrix $\mathsf{A}$ is [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) which has special form in [Toepliz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#CITEREFB.C3.B6ttcherGrudsky2012). Then each one side are $N=2n+1$. Furthermore, it can be diagonalized and generated the diagonal matrix $\mathsf{D}$ using [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) $\mathsf{W}$:

$$
\mathsf{W}=\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{0,0} & \omega_{1,0} & \omega_{2,0} & \cdots & \omega_{N-1,0} \\
\omega_{0,1} & \omega_{1,1} & \omega_{2,1} & \cdots & \omega_{N-1,1} \\ 
\vdots       & \ddots       & \ddots       & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots       & \ddots       & \omega_{j,k} & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots       & \ddots       & \ddots       & \ddots & \vdots \\
\omega_{0,N-1} & \cdots       & \cdots       & \cdots & \omega_{N-1,N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where,

$$
\omega_{j,k}=\exp\biggl(\cfrac{2\pi i}{N}jk\biggr)
\ \ \ \ (j,k=0,1,\cdots,N-1).
$$

Therefore the explicit solution to $\boldsymbol{b}$ is follows:

$$
\boldsymbol{b}=
\mathsf{W}^{\text{T}}\mathsf{D}^{-1}\mathsf{W} \ 
\boldsymbol{v}
$$

where $\mathsf{D}$ is:

$$
\mathsf{D}=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_{-k}\omega_{j,k}
& (j=k) \\ \\
0 & (\text{otherwise})
\end{cases}
$$

Then, each diagonal elements show the eigenvalues of $\mathsf{A}$. Furthermore, $b_{j}$ can be expressed by the expansion form as follows:

$$
b_{j+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}
\begin{bmatrix}
\displaystyle
\sum_{l=0}^{2n}
\cfrac{w_{j,l}w_{2n,l}
}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_{-k}\omega_{j,k}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This did not help, but was fun:

Let us try this for a finite sum:
$$
1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_0 \\
b_{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{-1} \\
b_0 \\
b_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For $k=1$:
$$
0 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
b_1 \\
b_0
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{-1} \\
b_0 \\
b_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This leads to the equations
$$
a^\top D^{(k)} b = \delta_{k0}
$$
for a matrix $D^{(k)}$ with components
$$
d_{ij}^{(k)} = \delta_{(k-i)j}
$$
where we also use negative indices for the matrix elements, thus having the center element at $d_{00}^{(k)}$.

This leads to a matrix equation
$$
A b = y
$$
with 
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
       & \vdots       & \vdots & \vdots \\
\dotsb & a_0 & a_{-1} & a_{-2} & \dotsb \\
\dotsb & a_1 & a_0    & a_{-1} & \dotsb \\
\dotsb & a_2 & a_1    & a_{0}  & \dotsb \\
       & \vdots       & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
\vdots \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the formal solution
$$
b = A^{-1} y 
$$
which is the central column of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: We could add that the matrix has a special kind of structure, it is a **Toepliz** matrix, which can have properties which allow for numerical advantages sometimes. Obviously if we keep check of the index, we only need to store $2n$ rather than $n^2$ values for the matrix if we explicitly built it as if it had to be able to store generic values in it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start and consider the case in which the sequences are limited,
with indices running within $\left[ {0,h } \right]$, i.e. let's translate the problem as:

$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  a_{\;j}  = 0,\;b_{\;j}  = 0\quad \left| {\;j < 0\; \vee \;h < j} \right. \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,h} {a_{\;j} }  < \infty  \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,h} {a_{\;j} \,b_{\;k - j} }  = \delta _{\;0,\,k} \quad \left| {\;0\, \leqslant \,k,\,j\, \leqslant \,h} \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
 $$

which means that $\delta$ is the convolution of $a$ with $b$, which can be solved iteratively.
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a_{\;0} \,b_{\;0}  = 1 \hfill \cr 
  a_{\;0} \,b_{\;1}  + a_{\;1} \,b_{\;0}  = 0 \hfill \cr 
  \quad  \vdots  \hfill \cr 
  a_{\;0} \,b_{\;h}  + a_{\;1} \,b_{\;h - 1}  + \; \cdots \; + a_{\;h} \,b_{\;0}  = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  b_{\;0}  = 1/a_{\;0}  \hfill \cr 
  b_{\;1}  =  - {{a_{\;1} } \over {a_{\;0} }}\,b_{\;0}  =  - {{a_{\;1} } \over {a_{\;0} ^2 }} \hfill \cr 
  b_{\;2}  =  - {{a_{\;1} } \over {a_{\;0} }}\,b_{\;1}  - {{a_{\;2} } \over {a_{\;0} }}\,b_{\;0} \, = \left( {{1 \over {a_{\;1} }} - {{a_{\;1} } \over {a_{\;0} }}} \right)\,b_{\;1} \, =  - {1 \over {a_{\;0} ^2 }}\left( {1 - {{a_{\;1} ^2 } \over {a_{\;0} }}} \right)\, \hfill \cr 
  \quad  \vdots  \hfill \cr 
  a_{\;0} \,b_{\;n + 1}  =  - (a_{\;1} \,b_{\;n}  + \; \cdots \; + a_{\;n + 1} \,b_{\;0} ) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

But being a convolution, it also means that it is the product of (formal) unilateral power series,
i.e. **unilateral z-Tranforms**.
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  A(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,h} \right)} {a_{\;k} \,x^{\,k} }  \hfill \cr 
  B(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,h} \right)} {b_{\;k} \,x^{\,k} }  \hfill \cr 
  A(1) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,\left( { \le \,h} \right)} {a_{\;k} }  < \infty  \hfill \cr 
  1 = A(x)B(x) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

so that if $A(x)$ is a known polynomial/function, $B(x)$ will be its reciprocal, and it might result into an infinite sequence

If the sequences are bilateral, like as you propose, then we move to **bilateral z-Tranforms**.

Finally, besides z-Transform, one may also consider to work with Discrete and/or Discrete-Time Fourier transforms.