# Functional Equation: $b(z)$ that solves $b(z)b(z^{-1})=1+a(z)a(z^{-1})$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

Given an analytic function $a:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, I need to find an analytic function $b:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ that satisfies

$$b(z)b\left(z^{-1}\right)=1+a(z)a\left(z^{-1}\right)$$

for all $z \in \mathbb C.$

Looks simple enough, but I don't know of a good way to start. Hints or references are welcome.

Comment: Who says such a function exists in the first place? Well, being analytic, both may be represented by power series around $z=1$, and then the terms of $b$ may be found one by one. Not that I expect it to end up in a nice closed-form expression, though.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That line of thought lead me to this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837062/287326). A proof that such a function does not exist would be sufficient for my purposes actually. One of the answers to that question states this impossibility without proving it.

Comment: You won't find a _general_ proof of impossibility, because at least in some cases the said function **does** exist. Say, $a(z)=z,\,b(z)=\sqrt2z$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks. You are right: $a(z)$ constant for instance. Perhaps a better way to ask the question is, what properties must $a(z)$ satisfy so that a solution exists? One condition which I think is sufficient is $a(z)=a(z^{-1})$. But this doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Then again, chances are it _always_ exists, we just don't know why.